# jquery dataTables DataTables warning: table id=IDtableU - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

This is my first time using jquery dataTable pulg-in and I am facing an issue that I can't understand. I am using the server side configuration with a Java EE servlet.

The problem that I get this error message: DataTables warning: table id=IDtableU - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0.

But when I have used Firebug to check the response that was sent from the servlet I found that it is the correct result.

this is my dataTable initialisation:

```
$('#IDtableU').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true, 
    "sAjaxSource":"/OCSReportingTool/updateuser",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", 
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "type_U": "Account type" }, 
        { "SAMAccName_U": "User Name" },
        { "statusAD":"Status in AD"},
        { "statusDB":"Status in DB"},
        { "department":"Department"},
        { "cc":"Cost Center"}
    ]
});
```

and this is the response (from firebug):

```
        {
    "aaData": [
        {
            "SAMAccName_U": "NULL",
            "cc": 0,
            "department": "NULL",
            "statusAD": "incactive",
            "statusDB": "incactive",
            "type_U": "local"
        },
        {
            "SAMAccName_U": "t_de_ri",
            "cc": 0,
            "department": "NULL",
            "statusAD": "incactive",
            "statusDB": "active",
            "type_U": "domain"
        },
        {
            "SAMAccName_U": "cbmr",
            "cc": 0,
            "department": "NULL",
            "statusAD": "incactive",
            "statusDB": "active",
            "type_U": "domain"
        },
        {
            "SAMAccName_U": "a_grzanowskim",
            "cc": 0,
            "department": "NULL",
            "statusAD": "active",
            "statusDB": "active",
            "type_U": "domain"
        },
        {
            "SAMAccName_U": "KuntzB",
            "cc": 0,
            "department": "NULL",
            "statusAD": "active",
            "statusDB": "active",
            "type_U": "domain"
        },
        {
            "SAMAccName_U": "a_orglmeisterm",
            "cc": 0,
            "department": "NULL",
            "statusAD": "active",
            "statusDB": "active",
            "type_U": "domain"
        },
        {
            "SAMAccName_U": "a_mauchg",
            "cc": 0,
            "department": "NULL",
            "statusAD": "active",
            "statusDB": "active",
            "type_U": "domain"
        },
        {
            "SAMAccName_U": "WittelS",
            "cc": 0,
            "department": "NULL",
            "statusAD": "active",
            "statusDB": "active",
            "type_U": "domain"
        },
        {
            "SAMAccName_U": "a_egloffm",
            "cc": 0,
            "department": "NULL",
            "statusAD": "active",
            "statusDB": "active",
            "type_U": "domain"
        },
        {
            "SAMAccName_U": "a_noetzoldr",
            "cc": 0,
            "department": "NULL",
            "statusAD": "active",
            "statusDB": "active",
            "type_U": "domain"
        }
    ],
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 10,
    "iTotalRecords": 6320,
    "sEcho": 1
}
```

this is my HTML:

```
<table id=IDtableU>
    <thead>
        <tr>     
            <th>User Name </th>
            <th>Account type </th>
            <th>Department </th>
            <th>Cost Center </th>
            <th>Status in AD </th>
            <th>Status in DB </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Really I need a help with this issue I have no idea how to deal with this.

Comment: Please show us the html part where you define the actual table. My guess is that you have a mismatch between columns defined in ths, tds and the json data.

Comment: Also please reformat your question because it is not readable.

Comment: Maybe the unnecessary comma at the the end of your columdefs is responsible for this issue. Also a "Datatables Warning" is not an Error message. It's just a Warning.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I have edited my question and I have added my HTML. For the comma it was a mistake when I have wrote the question but in the code there is no code

Comment: It's late in Germany. I'll start checking this tomorrow. Can you please check what happens if you leave out the aoColmuns for debugging purpose?